# Is there a way to plot data on a bar having colored sections defined by thresholds?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My problem is that I am trying to visualize data with thresholds rather than having to use text to describe it.

I have looked through some plotting libraries out there to try and find something like this and I came up empty. I am fairly new at python so any help would be appreciated.

```
if some_data_point < some_lower_threshold:
    print('data_point is lower with value of ' + str(some_data_point))

elif some_lower_threshold < some_data_point < some_low_threshold:
    print('data_point is low with value of ' + str(some_data_point))

elif some_low_threshold < some_data_point < some_high_threshold:
    print('data_point is normal with value of ' + str(some_data_point))

elif some_high_threshold < some_data_point < some_higher_threshold:
    print('data_point is high with value of ' + str(some_data_point))

elif some_higher_threshold < some_data_point:
    print('data_point is higher with value of ' + str(some_data_point))
```

The goal is to be able to quickly visualize a data point with provided thresholds unique to that data point. So the given data would be a single value and 4 thresholds. I guess looking like anything from here https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/html/images/colorbars.png but with an indicator on the value of some_data_point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [matplotlib.](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) This page shows the sort of graphs / bars you can make.

In your case, the [discrete distribution](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-horizontal-barchart-distribution-py) one looks the best.

Comment: That is a great link and there is a lot there but I am not sure what I could use for my intended purpose.

Comment: The discrete distribution one: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-horizontal-barchart-distribution-py. And if this is good, please accept the answer so others can see.

Comment: It looks good but I am not dealing with a distribution of data. Any suggestions on how I could change that to fit my purpose?

Comment: Try abr charts with gradients: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/gradient_bar.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-gradient-bar-py ... Then try making each threshhold value a string instead of a number *(not sure if possible with this library, but skimming it, you probably can cause it's in list form)*.

Comment: So after digging into pyplot more than I ever have, my problem is better described as plotting only on the X-axis.`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

higher_thresholds = [0, -16.00326]
high_thresholds = [-1.00015, -15.00313]
data_point = -3.54774

for item in higher_thresholds:

    plt.plot(item, 0, marker="D", color="r")

for item in high_thresholds:

    plt.plot(item, 0, marker="d", color="y")

plt.plot(data_point, 0, marker='.', color="k")

plt.show()`

Comment: I don't know any of these libraries, so I can't debug them for you. Your original question was about what was available to help solve your problem. I offered one that can, but you'll have to dig through it to see how.